# Cron job in webmin

Tags: cron

I have a webmin on Centos server. I want to create custom cron job. However there is cron job setting options available under "Scheduled Cron Jobs" tab. But if I want to set weekly cron then there it showing me only weekly(on Sunday). Instead of that I want to set cron on every Thursday. I also want to add time it should run at 4:30 pm on every Thursday. Please tell how I can find this option or how I can set as shell command in webmin.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to schedule it with Webmin, the Weekly on Sunday one is just a pre-built schedule. However, you can choose to create your own.

My reputation isn't high enough yet to post a picture, so please go here for a screenshot I created for you that shows how to create a schedule in Webmin to run your job every Thursday at midnight.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wjtguTr.png]

Edit: *I misread your question and created my screenshot to show a Tuesday schedule. However, once you look at it, it will be clear to you how to change it to Thursday. Sorry.*

Comment: Thanks I got it.But could you suggest me how I can add time. Suppose I want to run this at 4:30 pm at every Thursday.

Comment: Sure. Under _Weekdays_, select **Thursday**. Then, under _Hours_, select **16** (4pm) and under _Minutes_, select **30**.

Answer (score 0):

If the webmin software does not allow you to set it every Thursday, the easiest way is to just edit the crontab file directly using `crontab -e`. Assuming you have command-line access, just log in as the user you want to run the script, run the command, and edit the crontab file - there are good resources on the internet explaining the cron syntax.

If you do not know how to edit the file, or you do not have direct command line access, you can workaround it by running it daily, and having the script check if it is Thursday.